# Xquery For Complex payload

Tags: xquery

I have the input request like below

```
<Input>
<BIKey></BIKey>
<BusinessObjects>
      <BusinessObject>
        <BusinessIdentifiers>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuCode</BKey>
            <BValue>CDC</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuType</BKey>
            <BValue>123</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>CsmNo</BKey>
            <BValue>857895</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
        </BusinessIdentifiers>
        <BusinessAttributes>
          <BusinessAttribute>
            <BKey>Version</BKey>
            <BValue>1</BValue> 
          </BusinessAttribute>
          <BusinessAttribute>
            <BKey>date</BKey>
            <BValue>2018-06-28</BValue>
          </BusinessAttribute>
        </BusinessAttributes>
      </BusinessObject>
      <BusinessObject>
        <BusinessIdentifiers>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuCode</BKey>
            <BValue>CDC</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuType</BKey>
            <BValue>123</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>CsmNo</BKey>
            <BValue>34567</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
        </BusinessIdentifiers>
        <BusinessAttributes>
          <BusinessAttribute>
            <BKey>Version</BKey>
            <BValue>1</BValue> 
          </BusinessAttribute>
          <BusinessAttribute>
            <BKey>date</BKey>
            <BValue>2018-06-28</BValue>
          </BusinessAttribute>
        </BusinessAttributes>
      </BusinessObject>      
    </BusinessObjects>
    </Input>
```

and i would like to have the `<BIKey>` value should be all the values of `<BValue>` in for each `<BusinessObject>` separated by ':'
for the above example, the `<BIKey>` Values should be populated like below

```
<BIKey>CDC:123:857895:1:2018-06-28</BIKey>
<BIKey>CDC:123:34567:1:2018-06-28</BIKey>
```

i have tried like below

```
 <BIKey>
    {
        string-join(
            for $bo in Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject return string-join($bo/BusinessIdentifiers/BusinessIdentifier/BValue, '|'),
            ':'
        )
    }
    </BIKey>
```

But i am not meeting the exact requiremnt. Kindly suggest how to proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is what you want :

```
for $bo in Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject return <BIKey>{string-join($bo//BValue, ':')}</BIKey>
```

You can [try it here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/2b4ce69faaddc2f5755355624fc9f956).

Your XQuery code had the following problems :

- you created a single `<BIKey>` while you expected one per `BusinessObject` => move the `<BIKey>` tag in the `return` of the FLWOR instead of outside it
- you had a `string-join` using `|` as a separator
- you only joined the `BValue`s inside `BusinessIdentifier`s, but you also wanted those inside `BusinessAttribute`s

Comment: Can you help me with the other query [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538762/eclipse-xquery-for-complex-payload)